# Ajax Post in mvc returns error all the time

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I fairly new to Ajax post, and I wonder if someone could help me with why i keep getting the error message.

**`VideoController`**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Check(string userid, string streamid)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

The reason why the httppost is fairly empty yet is just to test if it works before i start writing the code.

**`Jquery`**

```
var userID = '@User.Identity.GetUserId()';
var defaultContext = window.location.hash === "" ? XSockets.Utils.guid() : window.location.hash.substr(1);
    //alert(defaultContext);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/video/check',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            userid: userID,
            streamid: defaultContext
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.status);
        }
    });
```

I keep getting throw into my `error: function` and if I debug I never hit the `[httpPost] Method`

Can someone help

**Update**

I get a 404 in the alert.

**RouteConfig**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: replace your error function with this to see what is the error:error: function (error) {
            alert(error.status);
        }

Comment: You could check your browser's network inspector for additional info.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Try without the `JSON.stringify` and remove the contentType.  Alternatively, could be a route issue - show your routeconfig.cs

Comment: Change your url like this `'@Url.Action("Check", "Video")'`

Comment: 404 means that the url `/video/check` is not correct.    The route looks like the default, so shouldn't be an issue.  Harcoded path may not match your site which is why suggestions for `Url.Action` - What's the url of the view?

Comment: This is the URL : http://localhost: 1117/Video/Stream#f8de2b3d-dc48-479e-b087-f51133a8b45a (just added a space to it so it was visible)

Comment: Probably not the issue you're getting, but here's a [donetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zgv6Bo) with your code.  It goes to success when `dataType:'JSON'` is removed and goes to error with this in, but goes to error with 200 code... (so probably not your issue) but maybe you can use it to have a fiddle with the options outside your app.

Comment: Can you show us how your are invoking the javascript ajax call? through a button? For me your code is working without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Foo(string userid, string streamid)
{
    return new JsonResult{ Data = new {success = true}};
}
```

Client:

```
$.post('/home/foo',{userid:'123', streamid:'bar'}, function(r) {
    console.log(r);
});
```

EDIT - If you prefer the `$.ajax` way instead of $.`post`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/foo',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        userid: '123',
        streamid: 'bar'
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.success);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

The confusing thing is that you mix XSockets.NET with AJAX... When you have XSockets in there, why pass anything over HTTP with AJAX? You can just as easy pass it to XSockets and call your service layer from there. Just a friendly pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to hardcore the URL:

```
var tURL = '@Url.Action("Check", "Video")';
$.ajax({
        url: tURL ,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            userid: userID,
            streamid: defaultContext
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```